# React rest countries - adding informations about country

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I don't know how to add informations about country. If I add `<li>{response}</li>` in render function it shows me all informations but if I do `<li>{response.name}</li>` it doesn't show anything. Any ideas how to fix it? I'd be grateful for help

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            searchText: "",
            country: []
        };
    }
    onChangeHandle(event) {
        this.setState({ searchText: event.target.value });
    }
    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { searchText } = this.state;
        $.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/${searchText}`).success(
            function(response) {
                this.setState({ country: response });
            }.bind(this)
        );
    }

    render() {
        let response = JSON.stringify(this.state.country);
        return (
            <main>
                <section class="search">
                    <form onSubmit={event => this.onSubmit(event)}>
                        <h2>Country search engine</h2>
                        <input 
                            id="country-name" 
                            placeholder="e.g. Poland" 
                            type="text" 
                            onChange={event => this.onChangeHandle(event)}
                            value={this.state.searchText}
                        />
                    </form>
                </section>
                <section class="results">
                    <div class="country-info">
                        <ul id="countries">
                            <li>{response.name}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <footer>
                    <p>Michał Plebański</p>
                </footer>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default App; here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/{countryName}` would return an `Array` of result. So you should use `Array.map` to render the objects out:

```
<section class="results">
    <div class="country-info">
        <ul id="countries">
            {this.state.country.map(country => <li>{country .name}</li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If I do `JSON.parse` i get an error `Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` :/ No idea how to fix it

Comment: the main issue isn't `JSON.parse`, but you trying to handle an array incorrectly. I have updated my answer